# NEON: Unpacking int8x16_t into a pair of int16x8 & packing a pair of int16x8_t into a int8x16_t

Tags: c++, arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

I'm implementing a **NEON** version for **arm64** of an algorithm I made.

The problem I'm facing is:

*- How to unpack a `int8x16` into two `int16x8_t`, meaning that bytes are kind of "casted" to shorts?*
*- How to pack these two `int16x8_t` back into a `int8x16_t`?*

[image]

The reason I am trying to do this is to apply operations on a couple of vectorized shorts, without overflowing, and finally packing back the result into a `int8x16_t`.

Here is my SSE2 implementation for this problem:

**SSE2 unpacking:**

```
__m128i a1 = _mm_srai_epi16(_mm_unpacklo_epi8(input, input), 8);
__m128i a2 = _mm_srai_epi16(_mm_unpackhi_epi8(input, input), 8);
```

**SSE2 packing:**

```
__m128i output = _mm_packs_epi16(a1, a2);
```

Comment: You probably already know this, but with x86 SSE4.1 you'd use `pmovsx` (`cvtepi8_epi16(input)`) for the low half.  The operation you're implementing is "sign extension", so it's helpful to mention that for future searchers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes I know about it, but thanks for the precision, it can always help!

Comment: Related: [Loading 8-bit values using NEON/ARM](//stackoverflow.com/q/9037247) shows ARM SIMD has widening add/sub which might be even more efficient than sign-extending first, if it does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it e.g. like this with intrinsics:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arm_neon.h>

void func(int8_t *buf) {
    int8x16_t vec = vld1q_s8(buf); // load 16x int8_t
    int16x8_t short1 = vmovl_s8(vget_low_s8(vec)); // cast the first 8x int8_t to int16_t
    int16x8_t short2 = vmovl_s8(vget_high_s8(vec)); // cast the last 8x int8_t to int16_t
    short1 = vaddq_s16(short1, short1); // Do operation on int16
    short2 = vaddq_s16(short2, short2);
    vec = vcombine_s8(vmovn_s16(short1), vmovn_s16(short2)); // Cast back to int8_t and combine the two vectors
    vst1q_s8(buf, vec); // Store
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It really helps